# Select top N keys with highest values from HashMap and convert to list

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map of Map<Person, Integer>, and I want to return a list of top N Person with highest value. How can I do this in an elegant way?

I had tried using TreeMap and select top N to list, but I think there are way better ways to do this.

Comment: A `HashMap` has no intrinsically meaningful order. To find the top N items, you have to iterate over the entire collection, no way around it. This is true regardless of whether you want to order by values rather than keys.

Comment: a "trade memory for time trick" can be: To maintain *two* Maps! One (hashed) from keys to values, and one additional (sorted) from values to keys...

Comment: @xerx593 Indeed, (something like) this is what Python does for its `dict` class, and this often even outperforms classical hash tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Person,Integer> map = ....
List<Map.Entry<Person,Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort( entries, Comparator.comparing(
    Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> {
        return v2.compareTo(v1);
    }));
return entries.subList(0, 5);
```